# Getting rain data and rain forecast using openweather map API

Tags: json, openweathermap

I am having a hard time to call rain data from openweather map API. Have anyone ever tried calling the rain data of current weather and it's amount. Also, I have not been able to make predictions like it will rain. Like making the forecasts about rainfall probability.

I tried using `rain = data['weather'][0]['rain']`. I used the same way to call the temperature, description and humidity but on rain it does not work. I am on the free plan.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc rain and snow fields aren't always available

more details here:

https://openweathermap.org/current